# How to convert string into array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvasjs

I have problem with converting string into array object.

My string looks like `[{ label: "BSP", y: 3 },{ label: "BJP", y: 10 }]"}]` I want it to be like

```
[
  { label: "BSP", y: 3 },
  { label: "BJP", y: 10 }
]
```

**Problem description**

I was working on a chart [Canvas Js](https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/bar-chart-axis-scale-break/). I want the chart on some ajax request.

My sample code is

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: baseurl+"api/",
    data: postData,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(html) {
        var poll_result = JSON.parse(html); // html = [{"question":"Lorem ipsum","title":"Poll Result","data_option":"[{ label: \"BSP\", y: 3 },{ label: \"BJP\", y: 10 },{ label: \"Congress\", y: 4 },{ label: \"AAP\", y: 1 },{ label: \"SP\", y: 2 },{ label: \" SP\", y: 1 }]"}]

        var data_option = poll_result.data_option.replace(/\\/g, "");
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            animationEnabled: true,
            axisX: {
                interval: 10
            },
            axisY: {
                title: poll_result.title,
            },
            data: [{
                type: "bar",

                dataPoints: data_option
                // dataPoints: [ { label: "BSP", y: 3 }, { label: "BJP", y: 10 }, { label: "Congress", y: 4 }] // Working code
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
    }
});
```

Assigning variable directly is not working as I thing it considers it as a string. So I want the `data_option` to be look like as given on the reference.

**Edit 1**

My PHP array looks like

```
$output = Array
(
    [question] => Lorem ipsum
    [title] => Poll Result
    [data_option] => [{ label: "BSP", y: 3 },{ label: "BJP", y: 10 },{ label: "Congress", y: 4 },{ label: "AAP", y: 1 },{ label: "SP", y: 2 },{ label: " SP", y: 1 }]
)
```

which I converted into JSON and echoed.

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

**Edit 2**

My Real code structure is

```
$poll_output_result['question'] = 'Lorem ipsum';
$poll_output_result['title'] = 'Poll Result';
$poll_output_result['data_option'] = '';

foreach($poll_result as $result){
    $poll_output_result['data_option'] .= '{ label: "'.$result['user_choice'].'", y: '.$result['count'].' },';
}

$poll_output_result['data_option'] = trim($poll_output_result['data_option'], ',');
$poll_output_result['data_option'] = '['.$poll_output_result['data_option'].']';

echo json_encode($poll_output_result);
```

Comment: why not use a [JSON](http://json.org) compliant string?

Comment: I have array in PHP code converted it into JSON String.

Comment: but it does not look like a standard JSON, with quoted keys, for example.

Comment: PHP has json_encode() etc.

Comment: @Noface same method I have use to covert a array to json format

Comment: You have to precise By php, provided content will be encoded in JSON  ----

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('text' => 'omrele'));

Comment: @Yanis-git I didn't get you.

Comment: Does the chart work when you use the hard coded `dataPoints` array that is commented out? Really not clear what specific problem is

Comment: Yes. You can see in my question. I have added some commented value which is working code.

Comment: Never manually create json as you are doing in the updated php code. Simply make `$poll_output_result['data_option']` an array

Answer (score -1):

You original issue is return JSON answer from ajax request, instead, you receive plein text. Is why you have to JSON.parse your content.

To specify type of answer from your server, you have to add the right header to your response.

TODO that in PHP :

```
//In top of your php file
header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
//[...]
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

---

EDIT 1

Because you use JSON_ENCODE, you don't need to craft your own json, let PHP do it for your. Replace your code by this :

```
$poll_output_result['question'] = 'Lorem ipsum';
$poll_output_result['title'] = 'Poll Result';
$poll_output_result['data_option'] = [];

foreach($poll_result as $result){
    $poll_output_result['data_option'][] = [ 
        'label' => $result['user_choice'],
        'y' =>  $result['count']
    ];
}

echo json_encode($poll_output_result);
```

Comment: But the JSON answer is decoded well in by `JSON.parse(html)`

Comment: i have doubt, your key "data_option" on your PHP array have stringified json as value ? or real PHP structure ?

Comment: Ok. Let me add real PHP code structure in my question